# Find most repeated sequence of values

Tags: r, algorithm, sequence

Suppose I have a data frame that looks like this

```
    ITEM
  1  X
  2  A
  3  B
  4  C
  5  A
  6  F
  7  U
  8  A
  9  B
 10  C
 11  F
 12  U
```

How can I obtain the most common sequence of values in the 'ITEM' column?. In this case the most frequent sequence would be `A, B, C` since it appears in row 2 to 4 and 8 to 10.

I have already tried the function `rle`, as well as some of the solutions found here, and I haven't been lucky. Can I have a suggestion, hint, or package recommendation?

Comment: Any preference on whether you want solutions in base R, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse...?

Comment: But sequence `F,U` also occurs twice (rows 6,7 and 11,12). So should we also return `F,U` and `A,B,C` or only the latter (because it's the longest?)?

Comment: Sorry for seeing the comment this late. Actually when I wrote the example I didnt consider that case, but yes, in such case I'd rather return the longest one. And regarding how I rather have the solution, I don't which with package. Thanks a lot

Comment: Is there a minimum length? What if the input is `ABCDEFGHIJABCDEFGHIJAB`, do you want the nice long `ABCDEFGHIJ` sequence that is repeated twice or the short `AB` that is repeated 3 times? That is, do you want the longest thing that's repeated, or, of the things repeated the most you want the longest one?

Comment: Hi Gregor, no. There's no minimum length. If could really nice if I could also consider the minimum length, but I am aware that'd make everything way more complex.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want the longest non-overlapping sub-string. There's some good explanation about the dynamic programming solution [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-repeating-and-non-overlapping-substring/).

```
x = c("X", "A", "B", "C", "A", "F", "U", "A", "B", "C", "F", "U")
n = length(x)
m1 = sapply(x, function(i) sapply(x, function(j) as.integer(i == j)))
diag(m1) = 0
m1[lower.tri(m1)] = 0
m1
#   X A B C A F U A B C F U
# X 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# A 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
# B 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
# C 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
# A 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
# F 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
# U 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
# A 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# B 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# C 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# F 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# U 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

m2 = m1
for (i in 2:nrow(m1)){
    for (j in 2:nrow(m1)){
        if (m1[i-1, j-1] == 1 & m1[i, j] == 1){
            if (j - i > m2[i - 1, j - 1]){
                m2[i, j] = m2[i - 1, j - 1] + m2[i, j]
                m2[i - 1, j - 1] = 0
            } else {
                m2[i, j] = 0
            }
        }
    }
}
m2
#   X A B C A F U A B C F U
# X 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# A 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# B 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# C 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 0 0
# A 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
# F 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# U 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2
# A 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# B 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# C 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# F 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# U 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

ans_len = max(m2)
inds = c(which(m2 == ans_len, arr.ind = TRUE)[,2])
lapply(inds, function(ind) x[(ind - ans_len + 1):ind])
# [[1]]
# [1] "A" "B" "C"
```

Comment: This is nice, but it's O(2^N) where N = total length of input, so not scaleable. If we could assume an upper bound on sequence length (user3276768 can we?), that would keep it scaleable. Also, an empty `collapse = ""` string would make things visually more compact.

Comment: Haven't try the solution yet, but what @smci says is something I expect; the dataframe has over 100k rows. Ill report back once I try it. Thanks for the answer

Comment: My earlier comment was deleted where I mentioned the first version of this code did not find the sequence `F,U` which also occurs twice.

Comment: ...or at least it's O(N^2). Either way, getting a scaleable implementation is challenging.

Answer (score 1):

A `tidyverse` solution mixed with nested `apply` functions. The solution is generalized and will report the most frequent non-trivial consecutive sequence that appears at least twice--tie goes to the longer sequence.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Data
x <- data.frame(ITEM = c("X", "A", "B", "C", "A", "F", "U", "A", "B", "C", "F", "U"), stringsAsFactors = F)

# convert x to vector
y <- x$ITEM

# Create list to check for sequence of each length 2 through n/2
l <- lapply(2:floor(length(y)/2), function(a) sapply(1:a, function(x) y[(0 + x):(length(y) - a + x)])) %>% 
  lapply(as.data.frame) %>% 
  setNames(sapply(2:(length(.) + 1), function(a) paste0("Consecutive", a)))

# Show most frequent sequence(s), choosing the longest
lapply(1:length(l), function(x) (as.data.frame(table(do.call(paste, l[[x]])), stringsAsFactors = F) %>% 
                                   dplyr::mutate(length = nchar(Var1)) %>% 
                                   dplyr::filter(length == max(length) & Freq == max(Freq) & Freq > 1)) ) %>% 
  .[which(sapply(., nrow) > 0)] %>% 
  dplyr::bind_rows() %>% 
  dplyr::filter(Freq == max(Freq)) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(length == max(length)) %>% 
  dplyr::rename(Sequence = Var1) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-length)

#  Sequence Freq
#1    A B C    2
```

Comment: @Gregor Made the suggested edits. Thanks for your feedback. The only one I couldn't use was `lengths` because the code doesn't output empty data frames for the sequences with no repeats. They're actually 0x3 data frames so `lengths` returns "3" for each data frame element. Also, didn't bother with making sure that n >= 4 because who's running this if n < 4? OP can always add it in though if necessary. But all in all, things look better now.

Comment: Looks great! I'm clean up these comments now everything's incorporated.